# Is the <stack> component for Fluent UI the implementation of the grid layout?

Tags: javascript, fluent, office-ui-fabric

I believe the answer is yes, but I want to be sure as the Fluent, Fabric libraries appear to be in the process of being merged and, the documentation is a bit lacking. I am looking to validate that the  and `<Stack.Item/>` are the implementation of the grid layout system, and is a react component to replace using the css classes directly?

The primary reason I ask, is I want to make sure I can have a responsive UI based on container size.

Answer (score 2):

According to [docs](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/stack):

> A Stack is a container-type component that abstracts the implementation of a **flexbox** in order to define the layout of its children components.

Comment: Ah, ok, so not a grid. Thanks for that.